# Refer to the base class (not sealed) in order to create a collection of sealed classes

Tags: c#, c++-cx

I have a base C++/cx class that isn't sealed. And I have a bunch of classes that inherit from that base class that are sealed. I'm wondering how do I refer to the base non-sealed class in C# in order to create a C# collection of the sealed classes.

C++/cx:

```
ref class ConcreteClass sealed : AbstractBaseClass (a.k.a not sealed)
```

C#:

```
public static ObservableCollection<AbstractBaseClass> MyObjectCollection;
```

Comment: Why does it matter? What problem is it causing (or allowing)? The abstract class is the only common base class, so from an OO standpoint, no, there's no way to indicate that the collection contains only sealed types.

Comment: The problem is I can't create a C# collection of type `base class`. For example, I have a base class `fruit` and would like to have a collection of all my fruits. `bananas`, `apples` etc... not sure why it isn't letting me do this.

Comment: What is the error or warning?

Comment: It's just not showing up when I compile successfully and try to reference it in my C# code.

Comment: `It's just not showing up` What do you mean by that?

Comment: It compiles successfully, but neither `MyNamespace.ConcreteClass` or `MyNamespace.AbstractBaseClass` show up. I made sure the `ConcreteClass` is `public ref class`. I think I might be realizing you can't inherit from a none sealed class if you desire to have a `public ref class` for your implementation, because you can't have a `public ref class` for the base class (it can't be sealed thus can't be `public ref`). So the solution might be to implement interfaces. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `show up` What do you mean by that? **Where** are they not 'showing up'?

Comment: In C# land.....

Comment: @visc he is asking, does it not show up in intellisense but compiles, or does it give a compiler error if you manually enter the name in?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you get an error if you try to type it out. everything compiles just fine. i.e. it just not available to C#

Comment: So you get a intellisense error but the code that contains the refrence compiles and works even though Visual Studio's intelisense says it should not?

Comment: The C++/cx class compiles fine, but the class I'm trying to access in C# is not available. I suppose it's related to Peter's answer

Answer (score 1):

C++/CX will not let you have a public, non-sealed class unless it is a XAML type (based on `DependencyObject` - something you probably *don't* want to do).

The easy solution is to expose your `AbstractBaseClass` as a public interface instead, and then C# will be able to consume it and create the collection of the interface type (into which you can store the concrete classes).